# Nav Sidebar like on Google and Twitch

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout, sidebar

I'm trying to recreate this sidebar:

http://www.twitch.tv/directory

There's also one on Youtube:

http://www.youtube.com/

When the window height is too small a scrollbar appears in the sidebar, and no matter how large the window height is it's always stuck to the bottom. Then my content will go on the right side (the same as Youtube). Is there an online tutorial or recommendations I can follow to recreate this? I'm trying to find one but haven't had any luck. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're after might be j Panelmenu:
http://jpanelmenu.com/

Completely customisable. I have used this for a few businesses such as:

http://www.kapowinteractive.com.au/

If you bring the width in, you can see an icon pop up in the top left corner. Click it and the navigation opens up. I think this may be a good starting point for you.